# OWB mapping hangs or takes too long - possible lock?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-warehouse, oracle-warehouse-builder

I'm new to Oracle Warehouse Builder 11gR2, but already not loving it! I'm using it in a VM with 2GB RAM and on XP 32bits.

I have 9 mappings from flat files to target, from source relational BD to target, etc. The problem in 3 of those mappings seems to be when I join tables both from souce and the stage area. I don't know if it's relevant, but my source DB it's on this same machine as the stage area(target), but in different tablespaces.

I can show you:
**1- How I've created the source DB user tablespaces:**

```
CREATE TABLESPACE insrc DATAFILE 'C:\IN\tablespaces\in_src.dbf' SIZE 100M;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE insrc_temp TEMPFILE 'C:\IN\tablespaces\insrc_temp.dbf' SIZE 50M;
CREATE USER insrc IDENTIFIED BY insrc DEFAULT TABLESPACE insrc TEMPORARY TABLESPACE insrc_temp QUOTA 0 on system;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO insrc;
-- Grant this role to be able to import a dump file
GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE to insrc;
-- Grant this role to be able to export to a dump file
GRANT EXP_FULL_DATABASE to insrc;
```

and then, in cmd line I've imported like this: `imp SYSTEM/%PASSWORD_DO_ORACLE% FROMUSER=trab2 TOUSER=insrc file='trab2.DMP'`

**2- How i've created the tablespaces for the target stage area user tablespaces and roles:**

```
 CREATE TABLESPACE indw DATAFILE 'C:\IN\tablespaces\indw.dbf' SIZE 128M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 512K MAXSIZE 250M;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE indwtemp TEMPFILE 'C:\IN\tablespaces\indwtemp.dbf' SIZE 3M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 512K MAXSIZE 200M;
CREATE USER indw IDENTIFIED BY indw DEFAULT TABLESPACE indw TEMPORARY TABLESPACE indwtemp;
ALTER USER indw account unlock;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO indw;
-- grant all system privileges
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO indw; 
-- grant all ROLES
GRANT "OLAP_XS_ADMIN" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "WFS_USR_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "DELETE_CATALOG_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "HS_ADMIN_SELECT_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "CWM_USER" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "OLAP_DBA" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "OWB$CLIENT" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "RESOURCE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "OWB_DESIGNCENTER_VIEW" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "CTXAPP" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "GATHER_SYSTEM_STATISTICS" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "AUTHENTICATEDUSER" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "CONNECT" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "HS_ADMIN_EXECUTE_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "PLUSTRACE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "LOGSTDBY_ADMINISTRATOR" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "JAVADEBUGPRIV" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "XDB_WEBSERVICES_WITH_PUBLIC" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "XDBADMIN" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "XDB_WEBSERVICES_OVER_HTTP" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "CSW_USR_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "OLAPI_TRACE_USER" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "JAVAIDPRIV" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "DBFS_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "ADM_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASK" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "JAVA_DEPLOY" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "OEM_MONITOR" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "XDB_WEBSERVICES" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "JAVAUSERPRIV" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "MGMT_USER" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "OWB_USER" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "JAVA_ADMIN" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "JMXSERVER" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "SCHEDULER_ADMIN" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "WM_ADMIN_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "ORDADMIN" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "AQ_USER_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "RECOVERY_CATALOG_OWNER" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "OLAP_USER" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "DBA" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "JAVASYSPRIV" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "XDB_SET_INVOKER" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "HS_ADMIN_ROLE" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "EJBCLIENT" TO "INDW" ;
GRANT "OEM_ADVISOR" TO "INDW" ;
ALTER USER "INDW" DEFAULT ROLE "EXP_FULL_DATABASE","IMP_FULL_DATABASE";
-- Might be needed ...just in case
-- run plustrace.bat before grant this privilege
-- GRANT plustrace TO indw;
/* To create a database directory, a user requires the CREATE DIRECTORY and DROP DIRECTORY privileges.
When you create a Warehouse Builder user, these privileges are not automatically granted 
to the user. Therefore, the database administrator must explicitly grant these privileges 
to the Warehouse Builder user.*/
GRANT CREATE ANY DIRECTORY TO indw;
GRANT DROP ANY DIRECTORY TO indw;
```

One of the mappings with problems is the CLIENTS_MAPPING which needs CUSTOMERS (from src), COUNTRIES(from src), DEMOGRAPHY(from target) and CLIENT_LAST_BUY(from target too). The insertion is supposed to consist on 50,000 rows and it's taking more than 30min and there is no data, at all, on the the CLIENTS table.

This problem also occurs on other mappings that envolve tables form source and target. When I use just from one place or another, there is no problem.

I'll leave you my Power Designer auto-generated code for the table CLIENTS as mentioned above:

```
create table CLIENTS 
(
   CLIENT_ID            NUMBER               not null,
   CLIENT_ID_SRC        NUMBER,
   COUNTRY_ID_SRC       CHAR(2 BYTE),
   DEMOG_ID             NUMBER               not null,
   CLIENT_NAME          VARCHAR2(70),
   CLIENT_BIRTH_YEAR    NUMBER(4),
   CLIENT_PHONE         VARCHAR2(25),
   CLIENT_CREDIT_LIMIT  NUMBER,
   CLIENT_EMAIL         VARCHAR2(30),
   CLIENT_STREET_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(40),
   CLIENT_LAST_BUY      DATE,
   CLIENT_COUNTRY       VARCHAR2(40),
   CLIENT_STATE_PROVINCE VARCHAR2(50),
   CLIENT_CITY          VARCHAR2(50),
   constraint PK_CLIENTS primary key (CLIENT_ID)
);

/*==============================================================*/
/* Index: CLIENT_INFO_FK                                        */
/*==============================================================*/
create index CLIENT_INFO_FK on CLIENTS (
   DEMOG_ID ASC
); 

alter table CLIENTS
   add constraint FK_CLIENTS_INFO foreign key (DEMOG_ID)
      references DEMOGRAPHY (DEMOG_ID);
```

I'm logging on OWB GUI as rep_owner (with all the permissions). The strange thing is that my colleague has this exactly mapping running on his machine in OWB 11gR1 and with no problems. But he imported the source DB to the target user...and that's the only different thing that he did.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check DBA_RESUMABLE, you might be running out of temporary tablespace.

You may want to try to combine your tablespaces as much as possible.  The more you divide your storage, the easier it is for Oracle to run out of space.

Comment: Are you saying that I should try, for instance, have equal temporary files for both source and target..I will try the default, just to see if things run better this way. Thank you

Comment: I've altered users from source and target to use the default temp tablespace. Each users uses its tablespace, but the datafiles are not on oradata/sid folder has my colleague has created. Can this have such a huge impact like that?What can I do more to bust the execution of mapping?Because it isn't give me errors or timeout...but more than an hour has passed and I still have 0 rows inserted :(

Comment: If your schemas are on the same database, usually the best thing to do is to have them share the same tablespaces whenever possible.  For example, with your current setup you could not sort a result set larger than 200MB.  If you combine the two temp tablespaces that max size increases to 250MB.

In 11g, a good way to see what's happening with a running query is to look at the active report: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id=>'[YOUR SQL ID]', type=>'active') from dual;`

Comment: Ok, so I'm gonna try and put the same schemas, source and target, on the same tablespaces and use temp by default.Do yout think the maxsize is a problem?Or should I use another way to create the tablespace (

Comment: Just to give you all some feedback: I did share tablespaces (normal and temp that I've created) for source and target and one of those 3 mappings that use src and target are already mappping properly. But I did have to drop the fk constraints because they're giving me problems, but I don't know how because I've populated the child tables first. Do you think this is critical in DW?Dropping the foreign keys constraints?I don't think so ... but I'll keep you posted anyway. I think people deserve that.

Comment: @Nevermind: Yes, I would say it's critical to disable or drop as many constraints and indexes as possible.  It's usually much faster to rebuild objects than to modify them one row-at-a-time as a side-effect of some other operation.